# Pdf template not showing updated company address

Tags: netsuite

I just updated my company address.I want to reflect it on all the PDF template.
On "**Sales order**" it showing the updated address but on the "**packed slip"** pdf template it is still showing the old address.
Please suggest me what can be the reason that one template is showing the updated address but other one is showing the old one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Addresses on forms can come from several locations with the company address (`Setup -> Company -> Company Information`) being the first address.

You can also specify addresses at the subsidiary level (`Setup -> Company -> Subsidiaries`) and transactions will use the subsidiary address first, then the company address.  I believe subsidiaries are a OneWorld feature only.

Then, each custom form can specify its own address.  So, under `Customization -> Forms -> Transaction Forms -> Edit`, you can specify an address to be used for the given form.  This address will override addresses specified at the subsidiary and company levels.

Comment: Correction to Mike's comment about the One World. If you are using One World it will not source the Subsidiary address, a custom field is needed to pick up the subsidiary address. Please check SuiteAnswer "Answer Id: 35513".

For some reasons, NS is not picking up the subsidiary address.